# Is this a display port for high res?

Tags: windows-7, display, vga, displayport

Is this port (circled) a display port, if so what type ?
[image]

I'm considering this high res monitor(2560x1440) : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dell-U2715H-inch-Monitor-Black/dp/B00PRCRWRU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1462954136&sr=8-1&keywords=U2715H its display ports are  :

```
DisplayPorts 2
DVI ports 0
HDMI ports 2
Mini DisplayPort port(s) 1
```

I do have a VGA port on laptop but VGA I don't think will output res 2560x1440 ?

Can I use port in image (circled) to connect to one of ports ? :

```
DisplayPorts 2
DVI ports 0
HDMI ports 2
Mini DisplayPort port(s) 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use a most generic DP to DP cable to connect to one of the `DisplayPorts 2`, or a DP to mini-DP cable to `Mini DisplayPort port(s) 1`, or even a [passive DP to HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode) cable to one of the `HDMI ports 2` ([since HDMI 1.3 supports up to 2560x1600@60Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison), which is the optimal mode of Dell U2715H).

EDIT: FWIW, one of the `DisplayPorts 2` of U2715H is actually a "DisplayPort out" for [MST/daisy-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multiple_displays_on_single_DisplayPort_connector).

Comment: thanks or just DP to DP such as 'DP to DP cable' ? : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rankie%C2%AE-Plated-DisplayPort-Resolution-Meters/dp/B00YOP0T7G/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1462955690&sr=8-2-spons&keywords=displayport+cable&psc=1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean (`'DB to DB cable'`?) but the product you linked would work fine for you.